# How to add a style to biblatex on Ubuntu

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I'm trying to add the `windycity` style to biblatex on my Ubuntu 19.04 system.

The windycity styles consist of 4 styles - https://github.com/brianchase/windycity

I have tried:

1) to put the files in relevant directories in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex`

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/windycity.dbx
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/windycity.bbx
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/windycity.cbx
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american-windycity.lbx
```

2) looking at the structure with other dbx files and duplicating:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-windycity/windycity.dbx
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-windycity/windycity.bbx
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-windycity/windycity.cbx
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-windycity/american-windycity.lbx
```

3) putting the files in my document directory:

```
/home/tim/Documents/TuteReview/windycity.dbx
/home/tim/Documents/TuteReview/bbx/windycity.bbx
/home/tim/Documents/TuteReview/cbx/windycity.cbx
/home/tim/Documents/TuteReview/lbx/american-windycity.lbx
```

I'm using the command in my document: `\usepackage[style=windycity]{biblatex}` Without the style in brackets, it compiles without error.

I'm not sure what version of `biblatex` I have. `apt list --installed|grep biblatex` shows nothing.

Comment: Never put personal stuff into texmf-dist. It belongs in texmf-local. Did you remember to run texhash or similar afterwards (presumably as root). Latex does search the file system at essh run as it is a very slow process, we build a list of the files (via texhash) And search the list

Comment: It may make sense to install a vanilla TeX live from TUG instead of the (often outdated and frozen) TeX live from the Ubuntu repositories. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the four files to `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/biblatex-windycity/` where your can find `$TEXMFHOME` from:

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

LaTeX will search this automatically under Ubuntu (at least it does under Debian). There is no need to run `texhash`.

Comment: Thankyou. I had some really strange behaviour where the contents of $TEXMFHOME were deleted but now I can use `\usepackage[style=windycity]{biblatex}`